# How can I jack up a header for replacement?

Tags: framing, structural, replacement, interior, load

I am trying to replace the header of a load bearing wall above some pocket doors. I have already done the header over the other set of doors on the other end of the room with no issues. However, when attempting to jack up this header, it does not appear to move although I can hear cracking like things are moving. I do not want to keep jacking if I am going to cause more damage. I need to jack this up about an inch before installing the new header. Any advice or recommendations?

Comment: A) Provide a pics so we can see what you see. B) Are you 100% certain you have cut it free of all other framing material? C) What's above this? Are you separating framing up there? D) What's below this, are you lifting the wall off the floor joists?

Comment: You support the weight above the header, maybe by jacking up a bit, but an inch is way too much.  With the weight supported then you can remove the header by removing/cutting nails or cutting the header if needed.

Comment: I'd venture that you do _not_ need to jack your framing up an inch. That's a crazy amount. You need to jack it up about 1/4" at most--enough to slip new lumber in place. Any more and you're doing damage to drywall, flooring, and woodwork in the vicinity. Please revise to explain your situation better. I'm not sure what's happening. (Funny: I have a friend called Bryan Benjamin.)

Comment: If your ram is extending but the thingy isn't moving, then look at the material _under_ the jack.

Comment: @popham  That is what we get when assuming OP has supported the jack on something better than 1/2 inch plywood sub floor.